# How to use merge-with to create a list for duplicate keys in clojure

Tags: clojure

I first tried

```
(merge-with list maps)
```

it works on maps with single value,
but for something like

```
{:a [1 2]} {:a [2 3]} {:a [3 4]}
```

it gives me

```
{:a (([1 2] [2 3]) [3 4])}
```

But I would like to have

```
{:a ([1 2] [2 3] [3 4])}
```

I just found out that I could wrap vals of maps with vector:

```
(defn my-merge
  [& coll]
  (let [maps (map #(assoc % (first (keys %)) [(first (vals %))]) coll)]
    (apply merge-with concat maps)))
```

But the let binding seems too nested, Are there any simpler function I could use in place of concat? So I could have some one line code like :

```
(merge-with the-function maps)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1

```
(defn my-merge [f & mlist] 
  (into {} 
        (map (fn [[k v]] [k (apply f (map val v))]) 
             (group-by key (apply concat mlist)))))

(my-merge list
          {:a [1 2]} 
          {:a [2 3] :b :two} 
          {:a [3 4] :b :one})

=> {:a ([1 2] [2 3] [3 4]) :b (:two :one)}
```

Version 2

```
(defn my-merge [f initv & mlist] 
  (apply merge-with f 
         (apply merge-with (fn [_ _] initv) mlist)
         mlist))

(my-merge conj ()
          {:a [1 2]} 
          {:a [2 3] :b :two} 
          {:a [3 4] :b :one})

=> {:b (:one :two), :a ([3 4] [2 3] [1 2])}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(merge-with (fn [a b] 
  (if (list? a) 
      (conj a b) 
      (list a b))) 
  maps)

;; {:a ([3 4] [1 2] [2 3])}
```

It works but relies on the type of the output collections - list in this case. This was the shortest I came up with.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution also make sure that the order of the items in the list is based on the order of the maps.

```
(def maps [{:a [1 2]} 
          {:a [2 3] :b :two} 
          {:a [3 4] :b :one}])

(into {} (for [k (into #{} (mapcat keys maps))
               :let [obj (Object.)]]
           [k (filter (partial not= obj)
                      (map #(get % k obj) maps))]))

=> {:a ([1 2] [2 3] [3 4]), :b (:two :one)}
```